# Cannot implicitly convert List<double>' to 'double'

Tags: c#, winforms, double, implicit-conversion

Keeps throwing, what is wrong in this part of my code, when I want to return cells I receive this error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'double'    :

```
 public double readFileToList(string Path)
    {

        var cells = new List<double>();
        string path = label3.Text;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            double temp = 0;
            cells.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path)
                .Where(line => double.TryParse(line, out temp))
                .Select(l => temp)
                .ToList());
            int totalCount = cells.Count();
            cellsNo.Text = totalCount.ToString();

        }

       return cells;

    }
```

Comment: Well yeah, how would you *expect* that cast to work? Make sure your return type, and what you are actually returning, match. Also make sure that what *uses* the function matches the type as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say for certain without seeing your entire function but my guess would be that you have the return type of your function set to `double` instead of `List<double>`. This would cause the error you are seeing.

---

## Edit

Confirmed looking at your edit that this is your problem. Change the return type of your function to `List<double>` and you will be good to go! Your code should look like this:

```
public List<double> readFileToList(string Path)
    {

        var cells = new List<double>();
        string path = label3.Text;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            double temp = 0;
            cells.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path)
                .Where(line => double.TryParse(line, out temp))
                .Select(l => temp)
                .ToList());
            int totalCount = cells.Count();
            cellsNo.Text = totalCount.ToString();

        }

       return cells;

    }
```

Comment: While you are totally correct, without knowing the context its hard to 100% say that the problem is with the return type (as opposed to what is being returned). Given the method name, I'd agree with you though :)

Comment: @ShawnL I change to return List<double>cells; but I got more errors. Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments and  Invalid expression term 'double'

Comment: Please share your updated code so we can see what you haven now.

Comment: @ShawnL; thanks that one is solved. Can I ask you some questions which is related to another issue.

Comment: Sure. Check out my profile there is contact information on my website.